# QSqlDatabase::addDatabase() check if host exists

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite, qt4, ip-address

Currently I'm working on a C++ application using the qt framework to read a specific database from a mysql server or a sqlite3 file. I have the main UI to display the data and a login-dialog to connect to the database.

The dialog checks if the filename is valid and a sqlite3 database and now i need this check for a given IP address cause otherwise the program gets blocked.

Is is possible to check if the IP address in the network exists and maybe to check if the server is available?

Comment: I don't think this can be done directly using QSqlDatabase, but you could start a process "telnet address port" and check to see if there is a valid response from the server.